# multiple {n} count not giving result regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to build a regex for a string that will contain 8 numeric characters[0-9] and 1 alphabetic character[a-z] means a total of 9 characters. The position of the alphabetical character and numeric characters can be any means numeric characters can come first like `12345678a` or alphabetical character can come at the start like `a12345678`.

**For above, I have tried below regex:**

```
 (([0-9]{8}[^.aeiou])|([^.aeiou][0-9]{8}))
```

But it's selecting a string which has more than 9 characters. I have tested it on regex & you can check it's screenshot below.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0B1J.png)

Can anyone please help me to solve it? Thanks for your time.

Comment: *"But it's selecting a string which has more than 9 characters"* Because you don't have any start-of-input / end-of-input assertions. You need a `^` at the start and a `$` at the end. (I haven't checked the middle.)

Comment: i think `^.` is causing the issue. `[0-9]{8}[aeiou]|[aeiou][0-9]{8}` worked for me.

Comment: `\b([0-9]{8}[a-z]|[a-z][0-9]{8})\b` according to your description.

Comment: @JimishFotariya, It's not working for me at all.

Comment: @Jarod42, Not working.

Comment: From [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gP4rxy/1), it seems to match you expectations.

Comment: As I understand the letter can be anywhere in the string. If so, you could use the following regular expression for verification: `^(?=.{9}$)\d*[a-z]\d*$`. This breaks the testing into parts. The beginning-of-line anchor `^` and *positive lookahead* `(?=.{9}$)` asserts that the string contains `9` characters. The beginning-of-line anchor and `\d*[a-z]\d*$` asserts that the string contains one lowercase letter, anywhere in the string, and all other characters, if any, are digits. The positive lookahead ensures there must be `8` digits.